# How does Apple know you are developing iPhone apps on MacOS?

Tags: iphone

I know there is a requirement in their EULA, but I heard about people getting their apps developed on Windows into the app store.

How can Apple find out, or do they even know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't, so if you get a native compiler and toolset up and running on Windows, more power to you.

But realize that:

1. You will not be able to use a language that compiles to bytecode (that's Java, C# and the .Net languages, Perl/Python/Ruby, etc.).  Apple will most likely not allow any sort of interpreter through the App Store.
2. Chances are your tools will not contain an Interface Builder equivalent or an iPhone Simulator equivalent.  You're going to be writing a lot of code and spending a lot more time testing.
3. You won't have local documentation.  You'll either have to use Apple's website or rely on third-party documentation which may mix App Store-allowed and -forbidden methods without indicating which are which.
4. You won't have Xcode's editor, which is highly specialized for Objective-C.  You'll have to type a lot more.
5. You won't be able to get help as easily since you're not using the same tools as others.
6. You will never know when a bug is in your code, your tools, or your platform.  People using the official SDK can file bug reports on the tools just as easily as the platform.
7. Your tech support incidents are worthless, because you're violating your contracts.
8. If Apple ever *does* find out, you're likely to be kicked out of the App Store and all your work will be for nothing.  Unless you're an idiot, this thought will worry you.

If you're a hobbyist, these may be acceptable to avoid paying $400 for a used Mac mini, but if you're not a hobbyist...this is no way to run a business.  Pick up a used Mac and think of all the money you're *not* spending on a factory, a store, offices, inventory, or employees during your setup time.

Answer (score 4):

There is no sdk available for Windows. XCode only works on Mac OSX, how would one compile, test, and run the app if not on Mac OS X?

Comment: You know C#, java, hackintosh, etc. There are lots of articles on the net like how they used C# to write iphone games, etc.

Comment: Maybe for jail-break phones, not for something you could put in the app store.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think they know.  There's no official SDK for the PPC architecture, but some simple installer hacking yields a working binary for my Powerbook.  Similarly, if you get your code working on Windows, more power to you...